# manipulating lists to find different variables

Tags: python, list

The following is the first line from my list l:

```
 [0.0, 753.128, 990.43, 686.832, 366.922, -93.454, 1.0]
```

This is the result of:

```
 print l[0]
```

I want to take all the first element from all such *lines of my list and assign them to another list. How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
[ l[0] for l in lists ]
```

That would do it.  Nicer is to use `map`: you map a list of lists to a list of their heads:

```
map( lambda l: l[0], lists )
```

If performance is important, you may want to create an *iterator* over the heads of your lists:

```
heads = itertools.imap( lambda l: l[0], enumerate(lists))

for head in heads:
   print head
```

Comment: His original list is named `l` so your examples might be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Basic [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
another_list = [sublist[0] for sublist in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [[1,2,3], ['a','b','c'], [True, False]]

first_elements = [e[0] for e in a]

print first_elements

>>> [1, 'a', True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5,6,7,8]
>>> ab = [a, b]
>>> map (lambda x : x[0], ab)
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
newlist=[]
for l in lst:
    newlist.append(l[0])
```